# Cannot print char array

Tags: c++

I'm using turbo c++ for my school project. I know it's very old and I should use code blocks or MVC++, but I just use it for simple program for school. Okay so my problem is that I cannot print out char arrays. Here is my simple code

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

class abc
{
    private:
            int rno,m1,m2,tot;
            char sname[10],grade;
    public:
            void getinput()
            {
                cout<<"Enter roll no:"<<endl;
                cin>>rno;
                cout<<"\nEnter mark 1:"<<endl;
                cin>>m1;
                cout<<"\nEnter mark 2:"<<endl;
                cin>>m2;
                cout<<"\nEnter student name:"<<endl;
                cin>>sname;
                cout<<endl;
                // Getting the returns.
                //tot = gettotal();
                //grade = getgrade();
            }

            void gettotal()
            {
                tot = m1+m2;
                // Returning the total to getinput's "tot" part.
                //return (tot);
            }

            void getgrade()
            {
                if(tot >= 150)
                {
                    grade = 'A';
                }
                else if(tot >= 100)
                {
                    grade = 'B';
                }
                else
                {
                    grade = 'C';
                }
                // Returning the total to getinput's "grade" part.
                //return (grade);
            }

            void display()
            {
                cout<<sname<<"'s total grade ranks: "<<grade;
            }
 };


 void main()
 {
    abc a;
    a.getinput();
    a.gettotal();
    a.getgrade();
    a.display();
 }
```

As you can see, it asks for marks 1 and marks 2 and then calculate it and prints 'A','B' and 'C' depending on marks.

Okay so what I want is to print 'First','Second' and 'Third' instead of A,B,C.

Can someone help me on this please.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried? Because unlike your title, it looks like you can print out sname no problem?

Comment: I can print sname without any problem but not grade. Don't know what's the problem. It's just that I am having problem in defining grade to "First","Second" and "Third".

Comment: Try the method in my answer

Comment: How would your code print 'First', 'Second', 'Third' when that is nowhere in your code?

Comment: my suggestion would be to use `std::string` instead of `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
enum Grade{
    A,
    B,
    C,
};

const char * GetGradeStr(Grade grade){
    switch(grade){
    case A:return "First";
    case B:return "Second";
    case C:return "Third";
    }
}

char sname[10];
Grade grade;

...
    grade = A;

...
    cout<<sname<<"'s total grade ranks: "<<GetGradeStr(grade);
```

This makes grade into an enum, which means only the 3 values are valid values, and then returns the correct string as a "String Literal"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I can add something, to make things even clearer for you. You need to understand the difference between char arrays and pointers. A pointer is just a variable which points to some area in memory. You can `malloc` memory and store the address into a `char*` - this will behave similar to a char array. But it's not the same.

A char array (and any array in C/C++) has to have a known size at compile time. The compiler will then "allocate" this memory statically, as opposed to allocating at runtime via `malloc` or `new`. This array can now be implicitly converted to a `char*` - this is what happens when you print it, for example. Look at the following code:

```
char* foo = "Hello world";
```

What this actually does is something like this:

```
// Compiler generated "global constant",
// somewhere in your executable
const char fooString[] = "Hello world";

char* foo = fooString;
```

For every string literal you use in your code, the compiler will generate such a "global constant". By assigning to a char pointer, the pointer now points to that constant's memory address, therefore it's possible to print it, index it (`foo[2]`), copy it, etc.

If you're using char arrays, the compiler will also allocate space at compile time. The `char sname[10]` for example will cause every object of class `abc` to contain memory for 10 chars (in addition to the other members etc.) Now when you reference `sname` in your code, it's type will be `char[10]`, but it can be (implicitly) converted to `a`char*` pointing to the first char in the array. Now let's have a look at the following code:

```
grade = "First";
grade = "Second";
grade = "Third";
```

If we remember that string literals are converted to global constants, it actually is something like the following:

```
const char[] str1 = "First";
const char[] str2 = "Second";
const char[] str3 = "Third";

grade = str1;
grade = str2;
grade = str3;
```

As you might guess now, this will work nicely if `grade` is a char pointer: It will just point to one of the constant string literals, and can then be used to print it etc. But if `grade` is an array, the compiler sees an assignment from `char*` to `char[]` - which is not possible. But it is possible using `strcpy` - why? Because `strcpy` takes to char pointers as arguments. Thus, the compiler will implicitly convert the char array `grade` into a pointer to it's first element, and pass this to `strcpy`.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined **grade** to be a **char** and not a **char *** . Please update that to become **char *** then you can assign those values like 'First' etc

**Edit**

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

class abc
{
    private:
            int rno,m1,m2,tot;
            char sname[10];
            char * grade;
    public:
            void getinput()
            {
                cout<<"Enter roll no:"<<endl;
                cin>>rno;
                cout<<"\nEnter mark 1:"<<endl;
                cin>>m1;
                cout<<"\nEnter mark 2:"<<endl;
                cin>>m2;
                cout<<"\nEnter student name:"<<endl;
                cin>>sname;
                cout<<endl;
                // Getting the returns.
                //tot = gettotal();
                //grade = getgrade();
            }

            void gettotal()
            {
                tot = m1+m2;
                // Returning the total to getinput's "tot" part.
                //return (tot);
            }

            void getgrade()
            {
                if(tot >= 150)
                {
                    grade = "First";
                }
                else if(tot >= 100)
                {
                    grade = "Second";
                }
                else
                {
                    grade = "Third";
                }
                // Returning the total to getinput's "grade" part.
                //return (grade);
            }

            void display()
            {
                cout<<sname<<"'s total grade ranks: "<<grade;
            }
 };


 int main()
 {
    abc a;
    a.getinput();
    a.gettotal();
    a.getgrade();
    a.display();
 }
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm still at learning process in c++. I have already tried char grade[10] and then to define char garde[] = "First"; . Is that right? I'm sure I have done some stupid mistake there.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but when I compile it, it gave 3 errors telling "Lvalue required ... " on the grade lines.

Comment: Using a char array instead of a pointer, it won't be possible to simply assign string literals. Instead, something like `strcpy` would be required. Could you remove that suggestion, or clarify it?

Comment: OMG! That works like a charm. You really helped me out there. I haven't reached to char * grade in my lessons yet. Thanks alot again :)

Comment: @lethal-guitar using a char array was a mistake. Pointer was added when i last updated my suggestion

Comment: @Vicky Yes that was a mistake, it was updated in last revision

Comment: @DotNetZeZo Glad it helped. If your instructor would not allow you to use char * for now then use a char array and then use strcpy function like suggested by Vicky and lethal-guitar

Comment: strcpy is best option for you if you have not studied about char *